# How to say related term in Chinese

Tags: translation

I want to say

> Today I discovered that 得 has a related term 不得不 which is used to emphasize somebody had to do something they didn't want to.

In fact I'm not even sure what to call that relationship in English。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

相关词

Comment: So what would the full sentence be?

Comment: You can obviously change this to fit your needs but I would say something like....我今天发现了'得'还有一个相关的词语叫做'不得不'－这个词语就是表示人家被逼做一些他们不想做的事。

Comment: @SamuelParsonage The guy gave you what you wanted, I think it's only fair for you to upvote the answer and accept it in return. It's not fair to ask for a translation of the whole sentence in the answer without you showing any effort in doing so.

Comment: @deutschZuid I was hoping for some confirmation before accepting... I don't know have the knowledge to determine if his answer was correct or not. Nor is it something I can "test", I can only go of the answer and responses of other knowledgeable people reading the said answer... However, since you seem to insist it's correct, fine, I'll upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I think 相关词 is too vague in this context
Grammatically, I would say "double negative" 
Another similar term is
能  vs 不能不

Answer (score 1):

The word I would use is "unavoidable." (Could not be avoided.)